# unable to pass the user-data to the ec2 ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I am trying to pass the user-data script while starting a new ubuntu 13.04 ec2 instance. I am using the new AWS CLI. Here is the command which I am executing to pass the user-data.

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxxxxxxx --security-groups default --key-name ec2-keypair --user-data user-data.sh
```

Here is my user-data.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo cat > /etc/chef/firstboot.json << EOL
{"run_list": ["recipe['recipe']"]}
EOL
chef-client -j /etc/chef/firstboot.json > /tmp/initialize_client.log 2>&1
```

I have a AMI which is already installed with chef-client. I am passing a user-data bash script to run chef-client and run the recipe when ever a new instance gets booted.

I am not able to see any log or any kind of output after running the command it just creates the instances, thats it.

Kindly help me out!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `user-data` parameter syntax is wrong. It should be: `--user-data file://user-data.sh`
Please read [AWS CLI documentation](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli).

Comment: That might be what the github documents say but the tool and the other docs indicate something else : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html

Comment: The documentation for user data, a fantastic feature, is atrocious at best.